# How `fix f = let {x = f x} in x` is evaluated?

Tags: haskell, lazy-evaluation, evaluation, fixpoint-combinators

`fix f = let {x = f x} in x`

Talking about `let`, I thought that `let P = Q in R` would evaluate Q -> Q' then P is replaced by Q' in R, or: `R[P -> Q']`.

But in `fix` definition the Q depends on R, how to evaluate then?

I imagine that this is about lazy evaluation. Q' becomes a thunk, but I can't reason this in my head.

As a matter of context, I'm looking at **Y** combinator, it should find a fixed point of a function so if I have this function, `one x = 1`, then  `fix one == 1` must hold, right?

So `fix one = let {x = one x} in x`, but I can't see how `1` would emerge from that.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Talking about let, I thought that let `P = Q in R` would evaluate `Q -> Q'` then `P` is replaced by `Q'` in `R`, or: `R[P -> Q']`.

Morally, yes, but `P` is not immediately evaluated, it is evaluated when needed.

> But in fix definition the `Q` depends on `R`, how to evaluate then?

`Q` does not depend on `R`, it depends on `P`. This makes `P` depend on itself, recursively. This can lead to several different outcomes. Roughly put:

- If `Q` can not return any part of its result before evaluating `P`, then `P` represents an infinitely recursing computation, which does not terminate. For example,

  ```
  let x = x + 1 in x     -- loops forever with no result
  -- (GHC is able to catch this specific case and raise an exception instead,
  -- but it's an irrelevant detail)
  ```
- If `Q` can instead return a part of its result before needing to evaluate `P`, it does so.

  ```
  let x = 2 : x in x
  -- x = 2 : .... can be generated immediately
  -- This results in the infinite list 2:2:2:2:2:.....

  let x = (32, 10 + fst x) in x
  -- x = (32, ...) can be generated immediately
  -- hence x = (32, 10 + fst (32, ...)) = (32, 10+32) = (32, 42)
  ```

> I imagine that this is about lazy evaluation. `Q'` becomes a thunk, but I can't reason this in my head.

`P` is associated with a thunk. What matters is whether this thunk calls itself before returning some part of the output or not.

> As a matter of context, I'm looking at Y combinator, it should find a fixed point of a function so if I have this function. `one x = 1`, then `fix one == 1` must hold, right?

Yes.

> So `fix one = let x = one x in x`, but I can't see why `1` would emerge from that

We can compute it like this:

```
fix one
 = {- definition of fix -}
let x = one x in x
 = {- definition of x -}
let x = one x in one x
 = {- definition of one -}
let x = one x in 1
 = {- x is now irrelevant -}
1
```

Just expand the definitions. Keep recursive definitions around in case you need them again.

Comment: Amazing, thank you so much,. This was equational reasoning? I need to practice that

Comment: @geckos Yes, that's equational reasoning. Keep in mind that GHC might not follow those steps exactly (its runtime system is rather complex, using a ton of optimizations), but it is guaranteed to lead the the same result.

Comment: (I was too hasty in posting my answer before seeing the ending of your post... :))

Comment: _Q does not depend on R, it depends on P._  this is still gray to me, can you explaing more about it? To me P is like a label to Q'  in R

Comment: @geckos Consider `let x = f x in g x`. `f x` depends on `x`, not on `g x`.

Comment: Hmmmmm,  I think I get it `let x' = f x in g x''`. Supposing that all x are the same, I just mark it with ' to speak of each one. Now f depends on x, x' depends on f x and x'' depends on x' and g depends on x'' is this right?

Comment: @geckos Yes. To be pedantic I would say that `f x` depends on `x`, not that `f` depends on `x`. You say the latter only because you know that `f` is applied to `x`, so you mention `f` but you are thinking of `f x`.

Comment: Oh, sure f x depends on x, my bad. The only thing that doesn't fit in my head is, where the first x (in f x) is coming from. In fix definition for example, I can't see where x is coming from. In another language I would claim that x is undefined

Comment: @geckos It is a recursive definition, so you use it before it's fully defined. In imperative procedural languages you can write a function `def x(): if ... then use x() else ...` which calls itself. In Haskell, you can do that even for non-functions (because Haskell is lazy).

Comment: @chi oh, now make sense, thank you chi, is really hard to get this lazy evaluation in head after years using strict languages